# php adding addtional p tag into html during loop

Tags: php, html

I am experiencing strange behavior with my php. It is adding in an emoty paragraph in my html but I cannot figure out why.

I am looping over a json object that looks like this

```
{
    "1495147646442": {
        "description": "Wonderful!",
        "fileNames": [
            "1.jpg",
            "2.jpg"
        ]
    }
}
```

My php looks like the following.

```
<?php
  $json = file_get_contents('auction.json');
  $json = json_decode($json);

  foreach ($json as $obj)
    {

      echo "<div class='row'>";
      echo "<p>" . $obj->description . "</p>";

      for ($x = 0; $x < count($obj->fileNames); $x++)
      {      
        echo "<img class='col-md-6' src=" . $obj->fileNames[$x] . ">"; 
      }

      echo "</div>";

  }
?>
```

The resulting html looks like this:

```
<div class='row'>
  <p>Wonderful!</p>
  <img class='col-md-6' src="1.jpg">
  <img class='col-md-6' src="2.jpg">
</div>


<div class='row'>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

however, I expect just to get

```
<div class='row'>
  <p>Wonderful!</p>
  <img class='col-md-6' src="1.jpg">
  <img class='col-md-6' src="2.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: actually is an additional `div` in your code, so use the array instead of the object `json_decode($json, true);` =>  https://eval.in/800930 . Plus can you show us what do you really expect as result.

Comment: @Edwin updated the question, sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Just check $obj->description is not empty in your foreach loop.

<?php
  $json = file_get_contents('auction.json');
  $json = json_decode($json);

  foreach ($json as $obj)
    {
        if(isset($obj->description) && $obj->description != ''){

            echo "<div class='row'>";
            echo "<p>" . $obj->description . "</p>";

            for ($x = 0; $x < count($obj->fileNames); $x++)
            {      
            echo "<img class='col-md-6' src=" . $obj->fileNames[$x] . ">"; 
            }

            echo "</div>";
        }

  }
?>
```

Comment: I think he doesn't want the whole 2nd `div`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the array way from decoding `json_decode($json, true);` => [array way](https://eval.in/800930). Or the [object way](https://eval.in/800939) `json_decode($json);`.

A simple check that the `$obj` is object will suffice.